# Ruby Float Conversion to Cents

Tags: ruby

A user enters the string `'67.99'`.  I need to ultimately convert this into the integer `6799`.

In other words: convert the currency amount entered via a `string` into cents via `integer` data type.

I notice that this happens:

```
('67.99'.to_f * 100).to_i
#=> 6798
```

Not expected behavior.  I need to save it as `6799`, not `6798`.

The issue is multiplying this float number by 100:

```
'67.99'.to_f * 100
#=> 6798.999999999999
```

**Question**: How can I properly convert a decimal, entered as a string, into an integer?

Example input and output:

```
'67'    #=> 6700
'67.'   #=> 6700
'67.9'  #=> 6790
'67.99' #=> 6799
```

IMO: this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) because I am aware that float is not broken.

Comment: You should not use floats to represent currency amount. Just try what happens if you calculate `0.10 + 0.20`...

Comment: There's also [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) for situations like this: `BigDecimal.new('67.99')`

Comment: @spickermann I am not doing any mathematical calculations on the float values.  I am only taking the string value entered in currency format and saving it as cents into the database.  Once there: I know It is safe to do mathematical calculations on the stored amounts as integers/cents. All mathematical calculations are on the integer values in the database. It is just a matter of properly converting them into integer values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Will the user always enter a string that matches the following pattern? `/^\d+\.\d{2}$/`. If so, you can simply delete the period with `String#delete` and then parse that with `String#to_i`.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), IMO. The author is clearly aware of the problems with floating point math already.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`round`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Integer.html#method-i-round):

```
('67.99'.to_f * 100).round
#=> 6799
```

As discussed in comments, there is a potentially better way to deal with such strings - [BigDecimal class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html):

```
(BigDecimal.new('67.99') * 100).round
#=> 6799
```

This becomes relevant for large numbers:

```
input = '1000000000000001'

(input.to_f * 100).round
#=> 100000000000000096

(BigDecimal.new(input) * 100).round
#=> 100000000000000100
```

Comment: ahhhh!  I knew it had to be round!  Thanks!

Comment: @Neil although this works for your test cases, keep in mind that `to_f` is a very basic conversion method. Users might enter `1,000.00` or `1,99` or `$100` and get surprising results.

Comment: Good point.  I'm good there.  The format of the currency input is validated beforehand to ensure it is a valid number and an expected number format as well.

Comment: This solves the user's immediate problem, but it would be far better to convert the string to a BigDecimal and round _that_ rather than converting the string to a float as the OP is doing.

Comment: @WayneConrad 1. Thx for downvote. 2. OP has gotten info about BigDecimal and potential benefits of its usage. I can of course edit the answer to emphasise it again

Comment: Comments are somewhat ephemeral, so I think that would be valuable to add that information to this answer, especially since it is checkmarked.  I worry that future seekers won't know that there's a better way.

Comment: @WayneConrad edited the answer with BigDecimal reference, if you feel there is more to it - please edit my answer :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I've added another example to show the difference. You might lose 4 cents per 1 quadrillion dollars :-)

Comment: @Stefan out loud! :D